# VB.NET Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have this HTML code:

`<td class="Class 1">Example</td><td class="Class2">Other Example</td>`

and I am trying to use Regular Expressions in VB.NET to extract "Example" and "Other Example"

`Dim parsedtext As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(htmlcode, ">(.+)<)`

(the htmlcode variable contains the html code mentioned above as a string.)

However, looking at 

`parsedtext(0).Groups(0)`

, it is returning "`>Example</td><td class="Class2">Other Example<"`. I do not understand why this is happening, and I have tried many other pattern strings and cannot figure this problem out. How would one extract all text between two specific characters such as > and < in the example above?

Comment: No. Stop. Don't parse (X)HTML with Regex!

Comment: BTW, VB.NET has no support for regular expressions. OTOH, .NET _does_ have regular expression support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @ColeJohnson (no one on SO is allowed to believe otherwise, at this point), but it's a good example for teaching the concept of **greedy versus non-greedy matching**.

By default, regular expressions quantifiers (`+`, `*`, `?`) "eat up" as much as possible, and only eat *less* when some part of the match fails. That's called *greedy* matching. To make it *non*-greedy, you use *non-greedy quantifiers*: `+?`, `*?`, `??`.

That is,

```
">(.+?)<"
```

In other words, your `.+` continued to match as many character as possible, before finding a `<`; so you see, your output was to be expected. If, however, hypothetically, it had *not* found that last `<`, it would have *backtracked* to the last time it "saw" a `<`.